# HTML Agility Pack find Descendants

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

i am doing crawling practice on a Web page and want to display some content on my Web page and I am stuck in code to find Descendants .
Below is the webpage HTML

```
<ul class="results">
    <li class="gts" data-webm-section="OAG-AD-14960184">
        <a class="item-link-container" href="/bikes/details/2016-Indian-Chieftain-Dark-Horse-MY17/OAG-AD-14960184/?cr=0&amp;gts=OAG-AD-14960184&amp;gtsviewtype=TopSpot&amp;gtssaleid=OAG-AD-14960184&amp;psq=%28%28Service%3D%5BBikesales%5D%26State%3D%5BNSW%5D%29%26%28%28%28%28SiloType%3D%5BBrand%20new%20bikes%20available%5D%7CSiloType%3D%5BBrand%20new%20bikes%20in%20stock%5D%29%7CSiloType%3D%5BDealer%20used%20bikes%5D%29%7CSiloType%3D%5BDemo%20%26%20near%20new%20bikes%5D%29%7CSiloType%3D%5BPrivate%20used%20bikes%5D%29%29&amp;pso=0&amp;pss=Premium">
            <header>
                <h3><span class=></span>Heading</h3>
                <div class="spotlight flag non-textual">Spotlight</div>
            </header>
            <div class="primary panel">
                <ul class="photos" data-js-lazy-load-length="3" style="width:8350px">
                    <li>
                        <img src="http//" height="221" width="334" alt="2016 Indian Chieftain Dark Horse MY17" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="image-nav previous" data-webm-clickvalue="previous-image">
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                    <span class="background"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="image-nav next" data-webm-clickvalue="next-image">
                    <span class="arrow"></span>
                    <span class="background"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="image-nav-count">
                    <span class="current">1</span> of 24
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="secondary panel">
                <span class="price">$29,995*</span>
                <div data-fancybox-href="/mvcajax/bikes/PriceGuide/" class="pricing-message light-box-iframe">
                    Ride Away No More To Pay
                </div>
                <div class="features">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="ui-category">
                            <i></i>Cruiser
                        </li>
                        <li class="engine-size">
                            <i></i>1,811 cc
                        </li>
                        <li class="odometer">
                            <i></i>2,552 km
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="bike-facts non-textual"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="description">**NO REGRETS - 7 Day Money Back guarantee** PLUS 12 months Warranty &amp; Roadside Assist.Conditions App...</p>

        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In above html I want image , price and category of bike

Below is my code

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Webcrawl()
    {
        string URL = "https://www.bikesales.com.au/bikes/new-south-wales/";
        List<bikes> bikelist = new List<bikes>();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var html = await client.GetStringAsync(URL);

            HtmlDocument Doc = new HtmlDocument();
            Doc.LoadHtml(html);

            var ProductsHtml = Doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("ul").Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("results")).ToList();

            var ProductsList = ProductsHtml[0].Descendants("li").Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("gts")).ToList();
            foreach (var list in ProductsList)
            {
                var PriceNode = list.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='secondary panel']");
                var bike = new bikes
                {
                    Name = list.Descendants("h3").FirstOrDefault().InnerText,
                    Title = list.Descendants("p").FirstOrDefault().InnerText,
                    Price = PriceNode.Descendants("span").FirstOrDefault().InnerText,
                    Image = list.SelectNodes("//div[@class='primary panel']/ul[1]/li[1]/img").FirstOrDefault().ChildAttributes("src").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                    Type = list.SelectNodes("//div[@class='secondary panel']/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]").FirstOrDefault().InnerText.Trim('\r', '\n', '\t'),
                    Engine = list.SelectNodes("//div[@class='secondary panel']/div[2]/ul[1]/li[2]").FirstOrDefault().InnerText.Trim('\r', '\n', '\t'),
                    Odometer = list.SelectNodes("//div[@class='secondary panel']/div[2]/ul[1]/li[3]").FirstOrDefault().InnerText.Trim('\r', '\n', '\t'),
                };
                bikelist.Add(bike);
            }
            return View(bikelist);
        }
    }
```

When I run the above Code I only get First element of the list except name i.e  same Image , same type , and same price.

Please correct my  mistake in code.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Basically for each node, that code is trying to get elements from the root, that's why you're getting duplicates.

Comment: Whats the Solution then?

Comment: once you have an html node have you tried using dot to specify you want to search from current element?

Comment: yes tried that also

Comment: I've noticed some of your xpaths returning null, please see solution bellow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To search from a specific element you need to use dot in your xpath. Otherwise search is carried out from the root of the document. Also I have written again some of these xpaths because they were not returning data in some cases.

```
var products = Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='results']/li[@class='gts']");
foreach (HtmlNode product in products)
{
    var PriceNode = product.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='secondary panel']");
    var bike = new bikes
    {
        Name = product.SelectSingleNode(".//li[@class='ui-category']").InnerText,
        Title = product.SelectSingleNode(".//header/h3").InnerText,
        Price = product.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='price']").InnerText,
        Image = product.SelectSingleNode(".//ul[@class='photos']//img").Attributes["src"].Value,
        Type = product.SelectSingleNode(".//li[@class='ui-category']").InnerText.Trim('\r', '\n', '\t'),
        Engine = product.SelectSingleNode(".//li[@class='engine-size']").InnerText.Trim('\r', '\n', '\t'),
        Odometer = product.SelectSingleNode(".//li[@class='odometer']").InnerText.Trim('\r', '\n', '\t'),
    };
    bikelist.Add(bike);
}
```

It generates:

```
Touring
2018 Indian Roadmaster Elite
$49,995*
Touring
1,811 cc
0 km

Cruiser
2018 Indian Scout
$19,995*
Cruiser
1,133 cc
301 km

Naked
2018 Suzuki GSX-S1000
$15,690*
Naked
999 cc
0 km

Touring
2017 Indian Roadmaster
$37,995*
Touring
1,811 cc
6,577 km

Super Sport
2018 Suzuki GSX-R600
$13,790*
Super Sport
599 cc
0 km

Cruiser
2018 Indian Scout
$18,995*
Cruiser
1,133 cc
1,901 km

...and so on
```

Comment: It Worked ..Thanks